# object detection in images

Tags: c++, c, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I have some sample images like this:

[image: Example image]

Now when a user uploads an image to my site I need to check if it contains the above images or a very similar variation of it.

I have tried to train a opencv haar classifier but the results don't seem promising. Not sure if I have generated the classifier incorrectly.

I have used the following commands to generate the haar classifier

```
opencv_createsamples -img logo.jpg -num 500 -bg negatives.dat -vec samples.vec -maxxangle 0.6 -maxyangle 0 -maxzangle 0.3 -maxidev 100 -bgcolor 0 -bgthresh 0 -w 209 -h 49

opencv_haartraining -data haarcascade -vec samples.vec -bg negatives.dat -nstages 10 -nsplits 2 -minhitrate 0.999 -maxfalsealarm 0.5 -npos 7000 -nneg 3019 -w 83 -h 35 -nonsym -mem 1024 -mode ALL
```

I'm using around 500 negative images.

Also would using a haar classifier be an overkill for my use case?

I have also tried using the `cvMatchTemplate` method in opencv with disappointing results. Although, the positive images are identified the false positive is unusually high.

Should I try training the classifier correctly? Also does running the haar trainer take an awfully long time.

Is this the right direction I am taking?

Answer (score 5):

You might have better results with **SIFT** in this case.

These are some interesting references:

- [Scale Invariant Feature Transform](http://www.aishack.in/2010/05/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform/)
- [Sift matching C++ source code / using opencv library](http://feelmare.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/sift-matching-c-source-code-using.html)
- [find-object](http://code.google.com/p/find-object/): Simple Qt interface to try OpenCV implementations of SIFT, SURF, FAST, BRIEF and other feature detectors and descriptors.

On a side note, **chapter 6** of [OpenCV tutorials](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/doc/opencv_tutorials.pdf) shows how to use the feature points **detectors**, **descriptors** and **matching** framework found inside OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks. I will to look into SIFT. I have tried the find-object but doesn't seem accurate enough.